# The fixed point of the group $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

Consider the group $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ act on a point $(z_1,z_2)$ in $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$, call the action $M$, then it looks like:
\begin{equation}
M(z_1,z_2)=\frac{az_1+bz_2}{cz_1+dz_2}=\frac{a\frac{z_1}{z_2}+b}{c\frac{z_1}{z_2}+d}\equiv\frac{aq+b}{cq+d},q\in \mathbb{Q}
\end{equation}

Now consider its fixed point:
\begin{equation}
\frac{aq+b}{cq+d}=q,ad-bc=1
\end{equation}

Which equals to solve
\begin{equation}
acq^2+(1+bc-a^2)q-ab=0
\end{equation}

Consider its $\Delta=\sqrt{4 a^2 b c+\left(-a^2+b c+1\right)^2}$:If it is a rational number, then the group $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ has two fixed points. But I have some trouble with determining the details about $a,b,c$. The core is to solve the Diophantine equation:
\begin{equation}
4 a^2 b c+\left(-a^2+b c+1\right)^2=\frac{m^2}{n^2},a,b,c,n,m\in \mathbb{Z}
\end{equation}

But I cannot handle it. I can just state that it has some non-zero solutions, for example $a=15, b=2,c=-96$, $\sqrt{4 a^2 b c+\left(-a^2+b c+1\right)^2}=16$, but I cannot give more details. So my question: can more details about this equation be given? Or which book should I refer to? Thanks.

Comment: It is not about the fixed point of the entire group, just of some element. It might help to think in terms of eigenvectors of the matrix corresponding to the given linear-fractional transformation.

Comment: @MoisheKohan The eigenvalues seem to vanish when I do this. $M(z_1,z_2)=\lambda (z_1,z_2)\rightarrow \frac{az_1+bz_2}{cz_1+dz_2}=\frac{\lambda z_1}{\lambda z_2}=\frac{aq+b}{cq+d}=q$, it is just the equation I posted. So what do you mean by "the fixed point of the entire group"? I think the space that the group acts on do not have such point that is invariant under every group element. (even $0$ is only invariant under $b=0$).

Comment: @MoisheKohan btw, I realize that using this method you can figure out the eigenvector without computing its eigenvalues and the null space. For a matrix in $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$, if the solution of the euqation $\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}=x$ is $x=x_1,x=x_2$, then its two eigenvectors are $v_1=(x_1,1),v_2=(x_2,1)$. This turns solving the eigenvectors to solving a quadratic equation. For higer dimension n, you just need to solve n-1 equations, for example, a $3\times 3$ matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a&b&c\\
d&e&f\\
g&h&i
\end{pmatrix}
$$
slove $\frac{ap+bq+c}{gp+hq+i}=p,\frac{dp+eq+f}{gp+hq+i}=q$